# Android 4.0 - Youtubestyled Tabhost - How is that possible?

Tags: android, android-layout, youtube, android-tabhost, android-style-tabhost

**What I try to do**

---

Hello Guys, I'm creating an app, and I want that it looks nice and simple to control. In my app I got a Tabhost with 3 Tabs. Every Tab is a fragment with diffrent content. Now its the problem, when I switch the tab. I have to do this over a click on the tabhost.

But if you take a look at the Youtube-App on Android 4.0 its possible to switch the tab over a swipe gesture. And exactly here I stuck, how is that possible.

I searched the web, took a look into the Android Documentation, but I didn't really find anything about this topic. So how is that possible to create something like that?

**Question**

---

What do I need to do, that I can switch in my tabhost like its done in the Youtube-App. If you have some great tutorials, code snippets or any other tipps, please post them.

Thx for your help in advance.

safari

**Pictures**

---

Here you find some pictures to explain better what I'd like to create. They are ordered chronologically.

[image: Number 1]
[image: Number 2]
[image: Number 3]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are using a [ViewPager](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html) for that.

Comment: do you also have a tutorial for this? That would be great! Thanks in advance!

Comment: I guess this one could work for you: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Support4Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv4/app/FragmentTabsPager.html

Answer (score 1):

ActionBarSherlock samples contains great examples of ViewPager+Fragments tabs:

http://goo.gl/GpbY4